# Read message from error queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rebus-rabbitmq

Each message sent through Rebus includes an ID. Rebus keeps track of this ID to determine if it’s been seen before, and how many times. If the subscriber is unavailable, Rebus will attempt to redeliver the message. If this redelivery fails a certain number of times, then the message will be forwarded to the error queue Rebus created for us.

Is there a way to read the message from error queue and proceed when the subscriber starts? If yes, please share the approach and sample code.